# Interpreting Anova Table correctly

Tags: probability, statistics

I performed ANOVA for the following information. Basically Rats where fed **low** amounts of food represented by 1 and **High** amounts of food represented by 2.
Underneath food 1 and food 2 is the amount of weight gained. I performed a one way ANOVA and got the following results. 
[image]

[image]

**My Question is if there is any difference between the rats fed by different amount of food.** 
The conclusion i came up with was that:
Since the F value is greater than the F Crit their is a significant difference.Is this the right way to approach this? Because my teacher said using the P-value would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since One-way ANOVA is a tool you can use when you want to compare the effects of more than two treatments, it would have been more appropriate had you performed a two-sample t-test. However, it is not wrong to use ANOVA for this purpose.

As a rule-of-thumb, if the F-ratio is greater than 5 this is an **indication** (not a proof) that *some* of the treatments have different effects on weight gain; with only two treatments, this indicates that they have significantly different effects on weight gain. Your F-ratio of 14 would seem to indicate that the average weight gains 95 and 80 are sufficiently far apart to be statistically significant.

If in reality the treatments are equally effective in influencing body weight (i.e., if the null hypothesis is true) then the p-value 0.04 indicates that your data do not fit well with this hypothesis; consequently, data suggests treatments have different impact on body weight.

Comment: Thanks a-lot Anders. I performed a two tailed t-test and got P-value of 0.0004 and compared to a significance level of 0.05, so as you stated the null hypothesis was rejected stating that their is a significant difference. THANKS :)

Comment: You are welcome. I'm happy to have been able to help. I notice that in your printout the p-value was not 0.04 but rather 0.04 *percent* which means that the p-value was 0.0004 (just as you got when performing the two-sample t-test).